# JSch disconnect and reopen channel causes exception channel is not opened

Tags: jsch

So I'm using Jsch to run multiple commands on remote servers. Currently I open one session, and whenever I need to run remote command, I open new exec channel, execute command, and disconnect.

However, I'm running into exception quite often (although not always). I'm wondering what is causing this exception. Is the reason because I disconnect and connect too fast? Or should I just reuse the exec channel instead of creating new one every time?

```
channel = session.openChannel("exec");
((ChannelExec)channel).setCommand(command);

/// some code goes here ///

channel.connect(); // <---- No Exception here

while (true) {
    if (channel.isClosed()) {
        exitCode = channel.getExitStatus();
        LOGGER.info("Exit code = " + exitCode);

        if (exitCode != 0) {
            throw new IOException("Command failed with code " + exitCode + " error = " + getError());
        }
        break;
    }
    Thread.sleep(1000);
}

channel.disconnect();

//// some code goes here ////

channel = session.openChannel("exec");
((ChannelExec)channel).setCommand(command);

/// some code goes here ///

channel.connect(); // <---- Sometimes exception here (JschException: channel is not opened)
```

Exception trace:

```
if(this.getRecipient()==-1){  // timeout
  throw new JSchException("channel is not opened.");
}
```

Any help is greatly appreciated !

Comment: Show us exception callstack. What version of JSch? I do not see any "channel is closed" exception in JSch code. Are you sure with the error message?

Comment: sorry it was actually channel is not opened. I've included code that raised the exception

Comment: You still have wrong message in question title + Did you check SSH server log file?